# collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status no DLL was created

Tags: c++, r, rcpp, r-package

Hello I am trying to make a package in R using Rcpp.
When I have just a single file, every thing is ok and my package(foad2) is compiled completely.
But, when I have more than one .cpp files (they do not depend on each other and each one contains only one function), I will be exposed to the following error

```
C:/RBuildTools/3.5/mingw_64/bin/g++ -std=gnu++11  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.3/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"C:/Users/Foad/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/Rcpp/include"        -O2 -Wall  -mtune=core2 -c myFunc.cpp -o myFunc.o
C:/RBuildTools/3.5/mingw_64/bin/g++ -std=gnu++11  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.3/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"C:/Users/Foad/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/Rcpp/include"        -O2 -Wall  -mtune=core2 -c rcpp_hello_world.cpp -o rcpp_hello_world.o
C:/RBuildTools/3.5/mingw_64/bin/g++ -std=gnu++11 -shared -s -static-libgcc -o foad2.dll tmp.def RcppExports.o myFunc.o rcpp_hello_world.o -LC:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.3/bin/x64 -lR
RcppExports.o:RcppExports.cpp:(.rdata+0x6f8): undefined reference to `_foad2_rcpp_myFunc'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
no DLL was created
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'foad2'
* removing 'C:/Users/Foad/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/foad2'

Exited with status 1.
```

**my Cpp Codes are:**

*my 1st cpp file:*

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
List rcpp_hello_world() {

    CharacterVector x = CharacterVector::create( "foo", "bar" )  ;
    NumericVector y   = NumericVector::create( 0.0, 1.0 ) ;
    List z            = List::create( x, y ) ;

    return z ;
}
```

*my 2nd cpp file:*

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector myFunc(NumericVector x) {
  return x * 2;
}
```

I would be greatful if anybody tell me how I can fix this problem?

Comment: Linker error.  Maybe your forget to run `compileAttributes()` ?  Maybe some symbols shadow each other?  Hard to tell -- in case like this I often suggest to go back to a working example and study what what be different.  Maybe try package `RcppExamples` ?

Comment: thank you your comment was help full, the name of the functions were not the same

Comment: Yes, that is (in its hard to deciper sometimes ways) what the linker signalled: something was referenced, but not supplied.  Glad you are all squared up now.